# Update of _ttl not working with doc option

Tags: elasticsearch, ttl

Hi I'm trying to update the ttl of a document with the following way but it seems that it is not getting updated:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/AU4Gd1DVbqjanfsolMgP/_update
{
"doc": {
"_ttl": 60000
},
"doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

With the script way it is getting updated normally.. What is the problem? does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only update it through script. From [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_parameters_3):

> It also allows to update the ttl of a document using ctx._ttl and timestamp using ctx._timestamp. Note that if the timestamp is not updated and not extracted from the _source it will be set to the update date.
>
> In addition to _source, the following variables are available through the ctx map: _index, _type, _id, _version, _routing, _parent, _timestamp, _ttl.

Comment: why not updating it with the doc option as well since from the documentation it states: "The update API also support passing a partial document, which will be merged into the existing document (simple recursive merge, inner merging of objects, replacing core "keys/values" and arrays)"

Comment: `_ttl` is not part of the document, i.e. `ctx.doc` and you can only update the document itself via the update API passing a partial document.

Comment: this makes more sense, so the only way to update the _ttl of a document is via script? other way without using script?